# Docker symfony 4 and mysql

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose

I dockerised my project symfony it  works well. I run command 
     sudo docker-compose run php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force.

And  I have this error :  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

docker-compose.yml

```
eversion: '2'
services:
nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
        - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - 3307:3307
    volumes:
        - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: nolan
      MYSQL_USER: nolan
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: nolan
    ports:
      - "8002:3307"
php:
    build: php7-fpm
    ports:
        - 9002:9000
    links:
        - db:mysql
    volumes:
        - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
        - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
```

.env symfony

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://nolan:nolan@0.0.0.0:8002/musiques
```

Comment: To me it looks like the DATABASE_URL is wrong. I would expect it to be `DATABASE_URL=mysql://nolan:nolan@db:3307/musiques`. `@db` references the db-service from your docker-compose.yml. The port `8002` is the one being exposed to your host system, but is not the one used between the containers

Comment: As far as I know the default port for mysql is `3306` though. So it might be that there is nothing running on the port you are exposing?

Comment: I change prot to 3306, i have same an error

Comment: The `could not find driver` could hint at a missing `pdo_mysql`driver. Could you also add your Dockerfile for the php container to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install php pdo MySQL package inside your php container.

Comment: si i have an other error An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requeste  
  d authentication method unknown to the client

Comment: Are you on mysql8?

Comment: If so I think they changed something with the hashes. But not sure. You should google it